# EngineYard how it works

Tags: engineyard

EngineYard has excellent supporters but their documentation is no doubt, the worst i've came across
Basically. I only want to know how EngineYard works under the scene.

1/ Which web server is EngineYard using (Nginx/Apache) ?
2/ On which instance the web server is installed on
3/ How may I apply some configuration changes to the web server 
4/ which cookbooks are always run by default

Answer (score 1):

1) EngineYard is using nginx. Check full technology stack [here](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/hc/en-us/articles/222896468-Engine-Yard-Gentoo-16-06-Technology-Stack)
2) You choose from [amazon instances types](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/hc/en-us/articles/205407898-Amazon-Instance-Type-Support) which to run
3) You can upload [custom cookbooks](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/hc/en-us/articles/205407438-Customize-Your-Environment-with-Chef-Recipes)
4) Cookbooks to configure [technology stack](https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/hc/en-us/articles/222896468-Engine-Yard-Gentoo-16-06-Technology-Stack) run by default. You will be able to look at them when you looged to your server with ssh.